# How can there be endangered humanoid species?

Tags: biology, fantasy-races, urban-fantasy, mythology

In my urban fantasy, I have several human species that coexist with humans. I'd imagine some like species such as who're classified as [Faeries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_beings_referred_to_as_fairies) have a stronghold to have intercommunication with humans. But as humans are still humans, they would endanger other species due to fear, hatred, or any other reason. Whether it be Ogres, Giants, Nagas, and more, their numbers are below average compared to other species, and reproduction wouldn't jix the problem.

So if most species made it to modern times, the problem is now about numbers. Let's say they breed in a rate of humans or even slower. What justification  would there be a reason to judge an entire species as non-threatened at best and endangered at worst?

Comment: "[Why would someone/something X?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130#6338)" questions are generally off-topic as too broad, [too story-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300), or [primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436#6437).  Please remember that SE's Q&A model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer.  As written, you've provided no criteria for judging the best answer and the phrase "entire species worldwide" makes the Q too broad.

Comment: The question is very unclear. Are you looking for numbers, that is, how many breeding individuals in a population of elephants (who reproduce pretty much as slow as humans) to classify it as least-concern, near-threatened, endangered etc.? Or are you looking for reasons for their extermination? We humans will find a reason, *any* reason. Ask the [Sorbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorbs), ask the [Livonians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livonians), ask the aboriginal [Tasmanians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aboriginal_Tasmanians), ask any number of American Indian tribes.

Comment: @AlexP I tired to ask for the former, but I admit I didn't word myself well.

Comment: I concur with JBH et al. Why questions are way too broad. You also answer your own question (humans being human; hatred; fear), so it is now extremely unclear what you're actually intending to ask! VTC on those grounds.

Comment: @TGCF -- it's okay if you didn't word yourself well! That's why you're able to edit your queries! If you edit this one to clarify your interest and also focus on one single problem or issue I'll happily retract my close vote!

Comment: What does "non-threatened at best and endangered at worst" mean? I tried to edit this question to make it more clear, but I admit I am not sure what exactly you are asking for. I have to go with "unclear what you are asking." @ me in comments with clarifications, and I can help you edit.

Comment: @kingledion They're the conversation status of the IUCN Red List of Threatened Species.

Comment: This question would benefit from the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168).  If you're using IUCN tags, what about their definitions is insufficient to answer your question?  Why are the measure of population and habitat insufficient?  I think the Sandbox would help a lot here.

Comment: ok, then what does "[faeries] have a stronghold to have intercommunication with humans" mean?

Comment: Wiki cites a definition of endangered species as fewer than 250 mature individuals in a single population: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endangered_species#Criteria_for_'Endangered_(EN)'_[7]  This obviously assumes that "faeries" can only reproduce with each other.